# Image does not line up in bootstrap

Tags: css

Here is my code I cannot understand why my image will not line up.

The last image leaves a rather large space above it. Help Im making a gallery of some piece of art.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="col-sm-12  col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="thumbnail"> <img src="images/Celeb. Portraits Tom    Waits, Tupac, Notorious BIG_2.jpg" alt="celeb" /></div>
  </a>
</section>
<section class="  col-sm-12  col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="images/music_2.jpg"="guitar" /></div>
  </a>
</section>
<section class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="thumbnail"> <img src="images/big man    house.jpg" alt="celeb" /></div>
  </a>
</section>
<section class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 clear">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="thumbnail"> <img src="images/elephant_2.jpg" alt="elephant" /></div>
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: do you mean there is a large space separating  the images in the first row and the images in the second row?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the different height of items on the top two images. To get them to appear in neat rows, put each group of two in a `div` with class `row`.

```
<div class="row">
  <section class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   ...
  </section>
  <section class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   ...
  </section>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <section class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   ...
  </section>
  <section class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   ...
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks figured it out